# Filter out non existing items

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables (with different fields) :

- tbl_Report (UIN, GID, RDate, RTS_a) > (UIN = unique nr.)
- tbl_Employee (GID, Sname, Gname, Org_Cd) > (GID = Unique 8 char string)

the link is 1 to many based on GID

tbl_Report: every Employee (GID) generates monthly one or more reports (RTS_a = SR, IR or OR) of each type

I want to create 2 queries:

- (1) for all Employees, so that I can see which employee delivered how many reports of specified type
  in each month, even if Employee didn't enter a report at all..
  RTS_a WHERE [ enter a Vald RTS_a]
  Year([Rdate]) Where [enter Year]
- (2) an overview for employees (selected by Report-type RTS_a) who didn't
  deliver a report vor a given year (Rdate) 
  RTS_a WHERE [ enter a Vald RTS_a]
  Year([Rdate]) Where [enter Year]
- the problem is I don't know how to get also the employees in it, who didn't entered data at all...
  I've tried in Query criteria under RTS_a : [enter a Valid RTS_a] ""or [enter a Valid RTS_a] Is Null
  but that doesn't seem to work
  (& somehow things went wrng when I tried using :
  WHERE NOT IN an WHERE NOT EXISTS)
- as a non native English speaking Access beginner... (and totally lost...)
  I could use some help on this....

Answer (score 0):

You got to use an `outer join`. In your query, in design mode, you should have both tables, and have a link between tbl_Employee.GID and tbl_Report.GID.
Double click the link (or right click and select Join Properties) and then click option 2 or 3 (the one saying you want ALL Employees and matching Reports.

---

Edit: for point(2), you have to make a query for those who DID enter data in [Enter Year], then make anther query, "outer joining" Employees and EmployeesWithoutDataInYearX `WHERE EmployeesWithoutDataInYearX.employeeId is Null`

Comment: I did come that far, though I Googled arround, and I suppose I need also a subquery...

my query looks now like:
TRANSFORM Count(tbl_Report.RTS_a) AS CountOfRTS_a
SELECT tbl_Employee.GID, Count(tbl_Report.GID) AS [GID total per Year]
FROM tbl_Employee LEFT JOIN tbl_Report ON tbl_Employee.GID = tbl_Report.GID
WHERE (((Year([Rdate]))=[enter Year]) AND ((tbl_Report.RTS_a)=[enter valid RTS_a]))
GROUP BY tbl_Employee.GID
PIVOT Format([RDate],"mmm") In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

but a subquery.... is the real problem I think...
:(